# In which thread does an IntentService launched by a Notification action run?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, android-notifications, intentservice

I have an IntentService wrapped in a PendingIntent that I want to launch when the user taps on a specific Notification action like this:

```
Intent actionIntentService = new Intent(context, ActionIntentService.class);
PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(app, getNotificationId(), actionIntentService, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

I then make sure to add an action with this pending intent to my Notification created via the NotificationCompat.Builder:

```
notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_notif_action, actionTitle, actionPendingIntent);
```

My question is, when the

```
onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
```

method of my IntentService is called, on which thread does it run?

I have debugged my code and it gives me the impression that this method call runs on the main thread. If that's the case, what do I have to do in order to make it run on a background thread?

**Edit:**

My ActionIntentService does extend IntentService

```
class ActionIntentService extends IntentService
```

Comment: IntentService runs OFF the main UI thread (that is the point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to documentation, the method you describe does not exist. You should extend [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and implement [onHandleIntent(Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent))

Documentation says:

> This method is invoked on the **worker thread** with a request to process.

Comment: My question is why onHandleIntent() is running on the main thread when invoked by tapping an Action in a Notification.

Comment: It does not. How do you know that? How do you check that?

Comment: Put a breakpoint, go into Threads tab, the name of the Thread is "main"